# How to integrate bootstrap Icons into Sitecore MVC Link Field

Tags: model-view-controller, sitecore, sitecore8

I have below HTML Code:

```
<a data-toggle="dropdown">Associate Sites<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
```

How can I implement  data-toggle attribute, bootstrap icon same as  into sitecore MVC field render like below syntax:

```
   @Html.Sitecore().BeginField("Link Field")
   @Html.Sitecore().Field("Destination URL", item)
   @Html.Sitecore().EndField()
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this.

```
@Html.Sitecore().Field("Destination URL", item, new { @data_toggle="dropdown" })
```

Or

```
   @Html.Sitecore().BeginField("Link Field", new { @data_toggle="dropdown" })
   @Html.Sitecore().Field("Destination URL", item)
   @Html.Sitecore().EndField()
```

Comment: I wrote like this  @Html.Sitecore().BeginField("Link Field")
                                    @Html.Sitecore().Field("Destination URL", item, new { @data-toggle="dropdown" })
                                    @Html.Sitecore().EndField() , but am getting error:Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

Comment: Can you just do @Html.Sitecore().Field("Destination URL", item, new { @data-toggle="dropdown" }) and not the begin and end?

Comment: Looking at code I have now that is close, try this.Move the new data toggle to the Begin Field. But I still dont think you need the BeginField EndField unless you are doing manipulation to the field.

@Html.Sitecore().BeginField("Link Field", new { @data-toggle="dropdown" })
   @Html.Sitecore().Field("Destination URL", item)
   @Html.Sitecore().EndField()

Comment: change `@data-toggle` to `@data_toggle` - hyphens are not valid in variable/property names in C#. The renderer should convert the underscores to hyphens

Comment: Guitar Rich to the rescue! I couldn't figure out how to get around the "-".